# How do I disable the nag dialog when closing a Remote Desktop session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When I'm running Remote Desktop and I close a window, I get a little nag dialog box that reminds me that my programs will keep running and that I can reconnect later. Thanks, RDC. I *know*. Then I have to press OK before it will actually close the window.

How do I disable this dialog?

(BTW, I'm runnning Win7, but the dialog is there in all versions of Windows.)

Comment: I find that message also extremely annoying.
A simple checkbox "don't show this again" would have been very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This will auto press the OK, and you'll almost not see it at all.

Install [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/)

write a script with a command like this

```
WinWaitActive("Remote Desktop Disconnected")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Run that before opening RDP.

If you get creative with your autoit script, you could have it always running, or launch only when you launch rdp client, etc.